# Arduino not sending numbers to SQL (via PHP) correctly

Tags: php, mysql, arduino

So, basically I'm trying to get some values from an Arduino board to be saved to my SQL database stored on my PC.

I've looked at multiple resources online, and spent about 5-6 hours trying to crack this, but now i'm here asking for your help.

So, Heres what seems to be working.

Im able to send values to the database Directly by typing in : 
[http://localhost/myapp/write_data.php?value1=2&value2=10]
to google chrome. This gives me the expected output from the PHP script and updates into the database. However, when I run it on the Arduino it goes through the code as if its working, but it isnt sending any data to the SQL Server.

Below is the Arduino Code.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

int rand1 = 0;
int rand2 = 0;



//EthServer(80);

//IPAddress server(10,0,0,1);
char server[] =("10.0.0.1");



EthernetClient client;


byte mac[] = {
  0x00, 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDE, 0x0
};

byte ip[] = { 10, 0, 0, 2 }; 



void setup(void)
{
  // start serial port
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
}

void printIPAddress()
{
  Serial.print("My IP address: ");
  for (byte thisByte = 0; thisByte < 4; thisByte++) {
    // print the value of each byte of the IP address:
    Serial.print(Ethernet.localIP()[thisByte], DEC);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println();
}

 void loop() {

  delay(1000);
    rand1 = random(1, 3);
    rand2 = random(25);
    Serial.println(rand1);
    Serial.println(rand2);

 // Connect to the server (your computer or web page)  
  if (client.connect(("http://10.0.0.1"), 80)) {
    client.print("GET /myapp/write_data.php?"); // This
    client.print("value1="); // This
    client.print(rand1); // And this is what we did in the testing section above. We are making a GET request just like we would from our browser but now with live data from the sensor
    client.print(";");
    client.print("value2=");
    client.print(rand2);
    client.println(" HTTP/1.1"); // Part of the GET request
    client.println("Host: 10.0.0.1"); // IMPORTANT: If you are using XAMPP you will have to find out the IP address of your computer and put it here (it is explained in previous article). If you have a web page, enter its address (ie.Host: "www.yourwebpage.com")
    client.println("Connection: close"); // Part of the GET request telling the server that we are over transmitting the message
    client.println(); // Empty line
    client.println(); // Empty line
    client.stop();    // Closing connection to server
  }
    else {

    // If Arduino can't connect to the server (your computer or web page)
    Serial.println("--> connection failed\n");
    printIPAddress();

  }
  delay(10000);

}
```

Then here I have the PHP Script

```
    //connect

    $link=new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "myappdb");

    //check connection

    if ($link==false) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        } 


    //insert values

    $sql = "INSERT INTO resistence (phase, max_reading) 
            VALUES (". $_GET['value1'] .",". $_GET['value2'].")";

    //// Check if values have been inserted, confirm with user that values are correct.

    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){

        echo "Records inserted successfully.";
        echo "Values inserted are Phase " . $_GET['value1']. " and Max_Reading ". $_GET['value2']. ".";
    }
        else
    {
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }

    /////


//close connection
mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Any help at all would be awesome.

Cheers
John

Comment: I think the PHP code is not relevant here, the IP address of your PC is 10.0.0.1? the http://10.0.0.1/myapp/write_data.php?value1=2&value2=10 url works? Try connecting from another PC, and check it if it works.

Comment: `client.connect` only accepts an IP or a domain not an URL.

Comment: Hey guys, the IP address is 192.168.179.1. I changed it in the code also because I thought my subnet might have been the issue. When I only use that however the client connect fails and I get the following in the serial monitor.

My IP address: 192.168.179.58.
1
12
--> connection failed

My IP address: 192.168.179.58.

Connecting to the same subnet from another PC works and I can append values to the database.

Cheers
John

Answer (score 0):

If you don't get reponse "connection failed" then it should be connected. Try

```
client.print("&");
```

instead

```
client.print(";");
```

If that still doesn't work, in the PHP file, use

```
error_log("text");
```

and check the server error.log to figure out if PHP script is even started, and check if $_GET variable is set at all.

EDIT: addition:

You shouldn't use client.connect in if statement.

[client.connect](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ClientConnect) returns an int (1,-1,-2,-3,-4) indicating connection status

```
SUCCESS 1
TIMED_OUT -1
INVALID_SERVER -2
TRUNCATED -3
INVALID_RESPONSE -4
```

So print out the return and then continue with debugging. Must be problem with the IP address you provided.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Wast. As a few people pointed out, as Im using Client.connect http://x.x.x.x, it wont work. but without it the connection fails.

Any other reason that the connection might fail in these pieces of code?

Cheers
John

Comment: Updated answer.